# How to write a transformer for Ruby Sanitize Gem to transform <br> into newlines?

Tags: html, ruby, lambda, sanitize

I'm using a wrapper for the Sanitize Gem's clean method to solve some our issues:

```
def remove_markup(html_str)
    html_str.gsub /(\<\/p\>)/, "#{$1}\n"
    marked_up = Sanitize.clean html_str

    ESCAPE_SEQUENCES.each do |esc_seq, ascii_seq|
      marked_up = marked_up.gsub('&' + esc_seq + ';', ascii_seq.chr)
    end
    marked_up
 end
```

I recently add the gsub two lines as a quick way to do what I wanted:
Replace insert a newline wherever a paragraph ended.

However, I'm sure this can be accomplished more elgantly with a Sanitize transformer.
Unfortunately, I think I must be misunderstanding a few things.  Here is an example of a transformer I wrote for the 
 tag that worked.

```
s2 = "<p>here is para 1<br> It's a nice paragraph</p><p>Don't forget para 2</p>"
br_to_nl = lambda do |env|
  node      = env[:node]
  node_name = env[:node_name]
  return if env[:is_whitelisted] || !node.element?
  return unless node_name == 'br'
  node.replace "\n"
end  

Sanitize.clean s2, :transformers => [br_to_nl]

=> " here is para 1\n It's a nice paragraph  Don't forget para 2 "
```

But I couldn't come up with a solution that would work well for `<p>` tags.
Should I add a text element to the node as a child?  How to make it show up immediately after the

element?

related question (answered) [How to use RubyGem Sanitize transformers to sanitize an unordered list into a comma seperated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614636/how-to-use-rubygem-sanitize-transformers-to-sanitize-an-unordered-list-into-a-co)

Comment: I don't see how this works; `gsub` returns the substituted string, `gsub!` replaces it in-place, which is what the current code seems to expect. And what's the question, is it about `<p>` tags, or `<br>` tags?

Comment: Dave, yeah, it's actually gsub!  I made a typo when copying over.
The question is actually about both <br> and <p> tags, whether there was a clean solution using transformers that would be robust and effective that didn't rely on the gsub hack.

Comment: I think I found a working solution:

https://gist.github.com/1831658

Comment: I'd consider making a quick hack to DRY up the first few lines of those two lambdas. But if it works, looks like my work here is done ;)

Comment: Hate to ask you to do my work, but I'm pretty new to Ruby blocks.
Any suggestions on how to consolidate the lines:
    `node      = env[:node]`,  
    `node_name = env[:node_name]`,  
    `return if env[:is_whitelisted] || !node.element?`,  

into a re-usable section of code, and how to make 

  `return unless node_name == 'br'`     

use a variable instead of a literall 'br'  

(That would allow me to in essence write 1 transformer, that accepts
the tag name, and then an actual transformation block as arguments.